# Wrong white background when converting SVG to PNG with gradient

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I want to convert SVG images to PNG keeping transparency. In the case of solid color shapes works fine, but when the shape is filled with a gradient, then the output image renders an unexpected solid white background.

I want some solution using Imagick library, but some code to preproccess svg code is also acceptable.

Here a minimal example of the issue:

```
<?php
$svg = <<<SVG
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100" height="100">
   <ellipse style="fill:red" cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50" />
</svg>
SVG;

$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($svg);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');

//IMAGE WITH NICE TRANSPARENT BACKGROUND
$img->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/circle_plain.png');


$svg = <<<SVG
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient1">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#ff0000;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0"/>
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#00ff00;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="1"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       xlink:href="#linearGradient1"
       id="linearGradient2"
       x1="0"
       y1="50"
       x2="100"
       y2="50"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
  </defs>
  <ellipse style="fill:url(#linearGradient2)" cx="50" cy="50" rx="50" ry="50" />
</svg>
SVG;

$img = new \Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($svg);
$img->setImageBackgroundColor('transparent');

//IMAGE WITH WRONG WHITE BACKGROUND!!
$img->writeImage(__DIR__ . '/circle_gradient.png');
```

Comment: ImageMagick tries to delegate SVG processing to external programs. What does `convert -list delegate | grep svg` tell you?

Comment: The `xlink:href="#linearGradient1"` definition reference is not understood by IM's internal SVG engine. Switching to RSVG delegate should help.